# how to reset form with image

Tags: html, forms, button, authentication

how to reset the form with an image ?

i found this on google

```
<button type="reset"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>img/hapus.png"</button>
```

and it shows like

[image: the image]

here, i want to make the reset button like the login button.

here is the code of my login button

```
<input type="image" src="<?php echo base_url();?>img/login.png">
```

here is my full code with code igniter

```
<table>
            <?php echo form_open('c_menu/index'); ?>
            <tr>
                <td>Username</td>
                <td><?php $inusername=array('name' => 'username', 'class' => 'GUI'); echo form_input($inusername); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo form_error(); ?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td><?php $inpassword=array('name' => 'password', 'class' => 'GUI', 'type' =>'password'); echo form_input($inpassword); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo form_error(); ?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Jabatan</td>
                <td><?php $injabatan=array('keuangan' => 'keuangan', 'hd' => 'head divisi', 'direktur' => 'direktur'); echo form_dropdown('jabatan',$injabatan,'keuangan','class = "gui"'); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo form_error(); ?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="image" src="<?php echo base_url();?>img/login.png"><input type="image" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>img/hapus.png" onclick="document.urfrom.reset()"/> </td>
                <td><?php echo form_error(); ?></td>
            </tr>
           <?php echo form_close(); ?>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if that is the case you will have to write code something like :

```
<input type="img" src="login.jpg" onclick="yourfunction()"/>

and 

for reset

<input type="img" src="hapus.jpg" onclick="document.urfrom.reset()"/>
```

you need to create 2 images logjn.jpg and hapus.jpg as well.

Comment: here is my code `<td><input type="image" src="<?php echo base_url();?>img/login.png"><input type="image" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>img/hapus.png" onclick="document.urfrom.reset()"/> </td>` and the `hapus` button still not working

Comment: also I would appreciate if you can paste your full html , that way we can match the form names in your code and the code that I gave

Comment: document.urfrom.reset() here urform should be replaced with the name of form which in this case I think is c_menu/index , or check the mapping for the form which is mapped against c_menu/index